# ActiveAndroid and Groovy

Tags: android, groovy, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, activeandroid

I'm using (or trying to use) Groovy language with Android Studio using this plugin: https://github.com/groovy/groovy-android-gradle-plugin

Everything works fine, but when I add ActiveAndroid (https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid) and call:

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        ActiveAndroid.initialize(this)
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Process: br.com.nglauber.testgroovy, PID: 1511
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:308)
        at com.activeandroid.ModelInfo.scanForModelClasses(ModelInfo.java:187)
        at com.activeandroid.ModelInfo.scanForModel(ModelInfo.java:152)
        at com.activeandroid.ModelInfo.<init>(ModelInfo.java:63)
        at com.activeandroid.Cache.initialize(Cache.java:66)
        at com.activeandroid.ActiveAndroid.initialize(ActiveAndroid.java:44)
        at com.activeandroid.ActiveAndroid.initialize(ActiveAndroid.java:34)
        at com.activeandroid.ActiveAndroid.initialize(ActiveAndroid.java:30)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite$StaticMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:148)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.call(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:88)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
        at br.com.nglauber.testgroovy.App.onCreate(App.groovy:14)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1011)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4518)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1339)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

My build.gradle is like bellow:

```
// Groovy
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url = 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.codehaus.groovy:gradle-groovy-android-plugin:0.3.5'
    }
}
// ActiveAndroid
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'groovyx.grooid.groovy-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.nglauber.testgroovy"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'

    // Groovy
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.4.0-rc-2:grooid'
    // Otto
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.5'
    // ActiveAndroid
    compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Have you added `compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.4.0:grooid'` to your dependencies as it says in the docs for the plugin?

Comment: hi @tim_yates, I added my build.gradle.

Comment: I just started having this issue after 5.1.0 OS update. Did you ever find a fix?